# overlay data over water but below land surface: Mapbox-gl.js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to overlay my data-layer on top of the water but below the land surface.

But the problem is that there is basically no "ground" layer on mapbox layers. There are different layers like 'water', 'roads' etc layered on top of a background which is basically 'land'

I have been able to use 'roads' on top on my data which gives the following images. but is there a way to visualize my data only on 'water' and not on 'land'?

For more information. data is in geojson format. I have used `movelayer()` funtion of mapbox and checked by moving my datalayer below each layer of `map.getStyle().layers` one by one.

Also, can this be done in different styles available in mapbox?

[image: street style]
[image: satellite-street style]
[image: dark style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you're trying to achieve, you'll have to find another tileset of land polygons to use as a mask. There isn't a way to dynamically clip a layer to within the polygons of another layer, for instance.

Comment: Are there more land polygon tilesets in mapbox library which do not come by default?

Comment: Natural Earth has a lot of useful data which can be downloaded and then uploaded to Mapbox as a tileset: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/. It's worth noting that you're running into this problem because, interestingly enough, the shapes of the landmasses you see in Mapbox Studio styles are built from the background layer. This layer has the same extent as the map canvas and is where landmass styles comes from. The water layer is a separate polygonal layer. The landmass shapes you see are a result of the water layer, which sits on top of the background layer and serves more as a polygon mask.

Comment: Yes, the land is nothing but the background masked by different layers. Thanks for the resource shared.